# Get Video from frames in Xuggler

Tags: java, eclipse, flash-builder, xuggle, xuggler

I am trying to encode a list of images into a video using xuggler. I have got an array of buffered images. I am using the following code.

```
public void encodeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, long timestamp) 
{

    //  BufferedImage worksWithXugglerBufferedImage = convertToType(originalImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    BufferedImage worksWithXugglerBufferedImage = convertToType(originalImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
    IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(worksWithXugglerBufferedImage, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

    IVideoPicture outFrame = converter.toPicture(worksWithXugglerBufferedImage, timestamp * 1000);
    outFrame.setQuality(0);


    outStreamCoder.encodeVideo(packet, outFrame, 0);

    if (packet.isComplete()) 
        outContainer.writePacket(packet); 

}
```

The problem is its returning me the following error..

```
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same width as this Coder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1204)
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same width as this Coder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1204)
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same width as this Coder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1204)
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same width as this Coder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1204)
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same width as this Coder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1204)
```

The error is generated due to `outFrame`, I have checked the width and height of the frame created and the picture its the same. Can any one help me out here or give me a hint..

I used the source present here. Thank you.

> http://wiki.xuggle.com/Encoding_Video_from_a_sequence_of_Images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is sir, You must be setting the height and width of your outstream wrongly. e.g

```
outStreamCoder.setHeight(height);
outStreamCoder.setWidth(width);
```

You should put your video height correctly here and so does your width.